# Can I use import statement of typescript as--- const pathToModule = './path/to/module'; import { abc } from pathToModule

Tags: angular, import, module, path

Can I use import statement of typescript as---

```
const pathToModule = './path/to/module';
import { abc } from pathToModule
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals are forced for import statements so unfortunately you cannot.

Comment: Thanks ...  actually I have wriiten a npm package file-path-resolver which works well with es5 but fails with this due to this restriction that you told. You can have a look on it here ... https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-path-resolver or https://github.com/sauravgaursmith/file-path-resolver